# Trying to set state from another component so that my modal can pop up

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

Hi I have two components `ExportReportRoomSelectionModal` & `Header` both have their own logic and state. I want to open Export Report Room Selection Modal via a button on Header component and for that, I have to set State on ExportReport.... to `show: true`. I've tried passing `handleShow function` as props to Headers.js then on header I want to hook it up to the elem that triggers the ExportReport....Modal. But I don't get any props on Header at all.

```
import Header from './Header.js';
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };

    this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleHide() {
    this.setState({show: false});
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({show: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal className="layout-scale-desktop layout-scale-45" onHide={this.handleHide} show={this.state.show}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Print PDF</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleSend}>Send PDF</Button>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
        <Header showModal={this.handleShow} />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { }; 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar navbar-default">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand" 
              <li>
                <a href="#" 
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  onClick={this.props.showModal}
                >
                {t("reports")}
                </a>
              </li>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: post the container component for both `Header` and `ExportReportRoomSelectionModal`

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your response please see my components thank you.

Comment: add `console.log(this.props)` at the start of `render` method , what do you see ?

Comment: doesnt have the one that i need which is showModal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it in other way round probably? You're putting your `<Header />` inside the `<Modal />` which is not mounted until you click on `<a/>` tag. Your modal should be inside the header & props should be passed down from the header.

It should be:

**Header**

```
import ExportReportRoomSelectionModal from "./yourmodal";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false
    }; 
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modalIsOpen: !prevState.modalIsOpen
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-oxehealth navbar-default">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand">
              <li>
                <a href="#" 
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  onClick={this.showModal}
                >
                {t("reports")}
                </a>
              </li>
            </a>
            <ExportReportRoomSelectionModal
               modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
               toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
             />
         </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Modal**

```
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        className="layout-scale-desktop layout-scale-45"
        onHide={this.props.toggleModal}
        show={this.props.modalIsOpen}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Print PDF</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body></Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleSend}>
            Send PDF
          </Button>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you Avanthika, much appreciated. You answer led me to right track and it works. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer was helpful to you, can you accept it please! :)